# Node.js: Framework or no Framework?

Tags: node.js, express, nodes, geddy

I am new to Node.js. I am very keen about learning it from scratch. I have a project which is like a Social media advertising web app. It won't be like Facebook, it is more like Myspace. It will be small at first, but it may become big in the future.

I would like to know if it's better to:

- Use Node.js without a ready-made framework
- Using an existing framework like Express, Geddy

I have done some research on sites out there using Node.js, and there are good sites that use a ready-made framework, and there are sites that don't. Is it worth creating our own site from scratch, or is it better to use a framework? Will using a framework restrict my ability to design my app and get in the way of learning Node.js?

So I would like to know that should I choose a framework or not. I am fine with learning Node.js from scratch and I'm not in a hurry or something.

The followup question is that there are lots of coding tutorials out there, but I would like some resources on the non-coding parts, such as software design, structure, etc..

Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: it depends on which features you need from the frameworks .

Comment: but isn't that we can install individual modules/npm libraries, middlewares on our project which are also used by frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Express, don't give it a second thought as a beginner.

While you may be interested in learning "from scratch" - you mention you are trying to develop a project which I assume should takes precedence over developing a framework.

Express, and node in general, is not that high-a-level of abstraction so you are not "losing" power as you may with a Java, etc framework.

You haven't mentioned anything hard or exotic that warrants a DIY framework.  Even if you need that at some point, you will gain experience in node/express way of doing things first.

Comment: will i be able to make flexible apps with Express or not, as i would like to have flexibility in development process.

Comment: @7zark7 , can you give more explanation to support your answer ?

Comment: Express for sure. Or maybe restify if you're only doing an api + backbone front-end hosted somewhere else.

Comment: @sam yes, try it for a few days, I think you will it see it's nothing but flexible.  Unless you really want a higher-level/all-in-one abstraction like meteor.com etc, I don't think you can go wrong.